# Looking to have a popup image retrieved from AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using AJAX to retrieve images into a page based on a radio button click.

```
                            <ul id="radio-attribute" class="radio-attribute">
            <li class="radio-attribute">
                <label for="radio_150" class="radio-attribute">
                <input type="radio" id="radio_150" name="Choose color" value="150" onClick="sendRequestSearch(this.value,7075)">
<img src="images/LimeGreenPMS368.jpg" alt="Green Tea" title=" Green Tea " width="25" height="25" />
</label>
</li>
```

This is working well.  The radio selects the correct image displays it etc.  What I would like is a pop up image expander verses it opening in a new page.

My AJAX scrip returns this:

```
echo '<a id="piGal" href="#" target="_blank" rel="fancybox"><img src=./images/' . $options['products_options_image'] . '></a>';
```

But it still opens a new window verses a popup.

I am not stuck on fancybox and actually would rather update to something more modern.

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Sounds like you need a modal. Have you looked into [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)?

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of jquery on the site, and was hoping that a simple solution would be available other then a total rewrite of the page, I am using the javascript function:

Comment: function createRequestObject() {
    var req;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
    req = NULL;
    alert('Problem with the XMLHttpRequest object');
    }
    return req;
 }

Comment: var http = createRequestObject();
    function sendRequestSearch(iets, pid) {
       http.open('get', 'ajaxproductimage.php?ovid='+iets+'&pid='+pid);
       http.onreadystatechange = handleResponseSearch;
       http.send(null);
    }

Comment: function handleResponseSearch() {
       if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
          if(http.responseText) {
             document.getElementById("piGal").innerHTML = http.responseText;
          } else {
             document.getElementById("piGal").innerHTML = " &nbsp; ";
          }

       } else {
          document.getElementById("piGal").innerHTML = " &nbsp; ";
       }
    }

Comment: I'm not sure what you're posting here, but you should edit you're original post and add the code in CODE FORMAT like this `code goes here`.

Comment: Im not sure, but... that target="_blank"  in ajax return.....  have you tried to remove it?